# Why was my answer deleted by a moderator

Tags: discussion, specific-answer

This looks not good. I have answered a question last week.  https://stackoverflow.com/q/11469085/603744. But this question was closed by a moderator today and my answer to this question was deleted to do so(which was actually a accepted answer). I really don't feel comfortable with this.

And this is the link to my answer if someone needs it https://stackoverflow.com/a/11469186/603744.

If a answer which was up voted and accepted is being deleted which in turn affects the reputation, so what is the use in putting efforts to answer or help someone here. And I don't know in what way my answer didn't meet the answering requirement in StackOverflow.

If someone states that the answer has to be deleted to close the question, why to delete the post which will definitely help someone. And the question was not that bad after all, except he had posted his code fully. And even the user has commented why he did it in his comment

> actually i post the relevant code,but some guys ask me to post full code.so i post it

Can someone explain me this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Sorry about that.  I deleted the answer.  It was actually a mistake on my part.  The *entire question* was to be deleted (there was a flag on it, and it wasn't a particularly good question).

I accidentally deleted your answer instead of the question.

Your answer has been undeleted, but the question has been deleted, which effectively has deleted your answer again (but not as a singular action targeted towards you).

Comment: The mixed messages police are gonna come lookin' for ya...or not.

Answer (score 0):

Your answer wasn't deleted in order to close the question. A question can be closed whether it's got an accepted answer or not.

I agree with you; I don't see why your answer was deleted. It answers the questions the OP asked for. It isn't VLQ.

The only thing I can think of is that your opening sentence was quite hand wavy:

> **IF** your Toast is not shown properly , there **might** be issue with the focussable attribute of your List Item. **Try** to set foucs to false for your Button. This **might** solve the first issue.

Which may have put the moderator in question off...