# Why was a question with an accepted answer deleted by a moderator?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, deleted-questions, deleted-answers, specific-answer

I was wondering why 25 rep. points on SO vanished, and found it was due to a moderator deleting [How do I create a GUI based network topology in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14680548/how-do-i-create-a-gui-based-network-topology-in-java/14681922#14681922)

What was the reason for deleting the question?

I have reviewed:

- [Why was my answer deleted by a moderator?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/152883/why-was-my-answer-deleted-by-a-moderator) A: Engaging in conversation.
- [Why was my answer deleted by a moderator](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/140084/why-was-my-answer-deleted-by-a-moderator) A: Low quality question.
- [Why was this answer deleted by a moderator?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/152403/why-was-this-answer-deleted-by-a-moderator) A: 'Link only' answer.
- [Why was an accepted answer I wrote deleted?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/159815/why-was-an-accepted-answer-i-wrote-deleted) A: Duplicated content from another answer.

The only one that might apply is 'low quality question' based on the question getting a down-vote (note that is one single down-vote, not 7 or 10).  OTOH the accepted answer was posted within 3 hours of and never needed editing, which suggests that the question is 'clear enough'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the history of the question you can tell that the question was closed as "Not a real question" with two down votes at about the same time as your answer was submitted.

After its closure you edited the question to add relevant tags, but you didn't vote to reopen it nor improve the contents. As a result, it was likely removed for the same reasons as the closure itself; I can't tell whether the existence of an accepted answer was considered in the decision to do so.

Comment: Silly me for not voting to reopen.  Thanks, that makes sense.

Comment: FWIW: the closure of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15043461/which-is-more-expensive-reading-from-text-files-for-every-iteration-or-storing) question was the impetus for the deletion of that asker's prior two questions - when someone asks several consecutive questions which are all closed, the system generates a flag so that moderators can do some cleanup / provide guidance / etc.

Comment: @Shog9  Thanks for the more detailed info.  (I missed it somehow, at the time!)